# How do I get the definition for a sense in NLTK's senseval module?

Tags: nltk, word-sense-disambiguation

In the NLTK `senseval` module, senses are of the form `HARD1`, `HARD2`, etc. (see source [here](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/senseval.html)). However, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the actual definition. I'm trying to implement the Lesk algorithm, and I'm now attempting to check whether the sense predicted by the Lesk algorithm is correct (using a definition from WordNet).

The problem I'm running into is how to unify the WordNet definition with the `senseval` answer (`HARD1`, `HARD2`). Does anybody know how to translate the SENSEVAL sense into a definition, or look it up somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finding out that these correspond to the senses in WordNet 1.7, which is pretty archaic (doesn't seem easily installable on Mac OS X or Ubuntu 11.04).

There are no online versions of WordNet 1.7 that I could find.

This site also has some useful information about these three corpora. For example, it says that the six senses of `interest` were taken from the  Longman English Dictionary Online (circa 2001). See [here](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/data.html)

It describes the source of HARD as WordNet 1.7.

Ultimately, I ended up manually mapping the definitions to those in WordNet 3.0. If you're interested, here's the dictionary. Note, however, that I'm not an expert on linguistics, and they're not exact

```
# A map of SENSEVAL senses to WordNet 3.0 senses.
# SENSEVAL-2 uses WordNet 1.7, which is no longer installable on most modern
# machines and is not the version that the NLTK comes with.
# As a consequence, we have to manually map the following
# senses to their equivalent(s).
SV_SENSE_MAP = {
    "HARD1": ["difficult.a.01"],    # not easy, requiring great physical or mental
    "HARD2": ["hard.a.02",          # dispassionate
              "difficult.a.01"],
    "HARD3": ["hard.a.03"],         # resisting weight or pressure
    "interest_1": ["interest.n.01"], # readiness to give attention
    "interest_2": ["interest.n.03"], # quality of causing attention to be given to
    "interest_3": ["pastime.n.01"],  # activity, etc. that one gives attention to
    "interest_4": ["sake.n.01"],     # advantage, advancement or favor
    "interest_5": ["interest.n.05"], # a share in a company or business
    "interest_6": ["interest.n.04"], # money paid for the use of money
    "cord": ["line.n.18"],          # something (as a cord or rope) that is long and thin and flexible
    "formation": ["line.n.01","line.n.03"], # a formation of people or things one beside another
    "text": ["line.n.05"],                 # text consisting of a row of words written across a page or computer screen
    "phone": ["telephone_line.n.02"],   # a telephone connection
    "product": ["line.n.22"],       # a particular kind of product or merchandise
    "division": ["line.n.29"],      # a conceptual separation or distinction
    "SERVE12": ["serve.v.02"],       # do duty or hold offices; serve in a specific function
    "SERVE10": ["serve.v.06"], # provide (usually but not necessarily food)
    "SERVE2": ["serve.v.01"],       # serve a purpose, role, or function
    "SERVE6": ["service.v.01"]      # be used by; as of a utility
}
```